In confluent kafka version 7.4.3-ccs, what are the ports 37421, 39821, 40223, 43597 and 43611 are used for and should they be opened by the firewall?
In confluent kafka version 7.4.3-ccs, what are the ports 37421, 39821, 40223, 43597 and 43611 are used for and should they be opened or closed by the firewall?
Why I cant seem to find these ports in Confluent literature?
Why are these ports different from all my brokers?
kafka-topics -version
**7.4.3-ccs** (Commit:58bc41cd9d6c788aee9a08c455ec7578fe9a71f2)

broker1.server.com - Profiles: burrow & kafka
[user1@broker1.server.com ~]# lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
prometheu    1579 prometheus    3u  IPv6    30642      0t0  TCP *:9100              (LISTEN) Open
java         1608      kafka  109u  IPv4    38682      0t0  TCP *:9131              (LISTEN) Open
**java         1608      kafka  117u  IPv4    38865      0t0  TCP *:37421           (LISTEN) Closed**
java         1608      kafka  887u  IPv4    41540      0t0  TCP 100.100.100.10:9093 (LISTEN) Open
burrow-1.    1613     burrow    8u  IPv6    30671      0t0  TCP *:9105              (LISTEN) Open

broker2.server.com Profiles:
[user2@broker2.server.com ~]# lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
prometheu    1542 prometheus    3u  IPv6    35984      0t0  TCP *:9100              (LISTEN) Open
java         9228      kafka  109u  IPv4    48803      0t0  TCP *:9131              (LISTEN) Open
**java         9228      kafka  117u  IPv4    48812      0t0  TCP *:39821           (LISTEN) Closed**
java         9228      kafka  710u  IPv4    50312      0t0  TCP 100.100.100.10:9093 (LISTEN) Open

broker3.server.com Profiles: burrow and kafka
[user3@broker3.server.com ~]#  lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
prometheu    1561 prometheus    3u  IPv6    40086      0t0  TCP *:9100              (LISTEN) Open
burrow-1.    1594     burrow    8u  IPv6    38288      0t0  TCP *:9105              (LISTEN) Open
java         1599      kafka  109u  IPv4    37378      0t0  TCP *:9131              (LISTEN) Open
**java         1599      kafka  117u  IPv4    39393      0t0  TCP *:40223           (LISTEN) Closed**
java         1599      kafka 1445u  IPv4    45879      0t0  TCP 100.100.100.10:9093 (LISTEN) Open

broker4.server.com Profiles: burrow and kafka
[user4@broker4.server.com ~]# lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
prometheu    1572 prometheus    3u  IPv6    36065      0t0  TCP *:9100              (LISTEN) Open
java         7866      kafka  109u  IPv4    44515      0t0  TCP *:9131              (LISTEN) Open
**java         7866      kafka  117u  IPv4    44524      0t0  TCP *:43597           (LISTEN) Closed**
java         7866      kafka  868u  IPv4    37731      0t0  TCP 100.100.100.10:9093 (LISTEN) Open

broker5.server.com Profiles: kafka
[user5@broker5.server.com ~]# lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
prometheu    1538 prometheus    3u  IPv6    35426      0t0  TCP *:9100              (LISTEN) Open
java         1583      kafka  109u  IPv4    39227      0t0  TCP *:9131              (LISTEN) Open
**java         1583      kafka  117u  IPv4    39290      0t0  TCP *:43611           (LISTEN) Closed**
java         1583      kafka  728u  IPv4    36191      0t0  TCP 100.100.100.10:9093 (LISTEN) Open

I expected CP kafka listener ports to be consistent throughout all brokers across all environments(DEV, UAT, PROD etc).
